# Counting packets in Wireshark

Tags: wireshark

Is it possible to re-do numbering in Wireshark. For example i have filtered packets to one side:

[image]

So the numbers are (they are not in order because of filtering):
416,419,420,423,424,426,427.

But i would like to number them like this, line by line:
1,2,3,4,5,6,7

The reason is that it would be easier to count all the packets. I know tshark has statistical operation COUNT, but for quick counting this would be a lot better.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can export the displayed packets into a new file via *File -> Export Specified Packets... -> All packets: Displayed*.  The new capture file will contain sequentially numbered packets starting from 1.

But if you just want to know how many displayed packets there are, you could just look at the Wireshark status line where it will indicate the number of displayed packets.

*Statistics -> Capture File Properties* will also tell you the number of displayed packets.